# How to scroll HMSegmentedControl horizontally to the selected index without manually scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]I am using `HMSegmentedControl` with 6 section titles(monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday).
When current day is friday then i want to scroll the `HMSegmentedControl` to the index of friday(i.e. index 4).
I have set `HMSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex` to the index of friday but it is not scrolling to that index.
when i manually click on friday then `HMSegmentedControl` scrolls.
Does anyone knows how i can achieve that.

```
segmentedControl = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[NSLocalizedString(@"MONDAY", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"TUESDAY", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"WEDNESDAY", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"THURSDAY", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"FRIDAY", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"SATURDAY", nil)]];

    segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    CGFloat viewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, viewWidth, 45);
    segmentedControl.segmentEdgeInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10);
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = [Nav_Bar_Color toColor];
    segmentedControl.selectionStyle = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleFullWidthStripe;
    segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorLocation = HMSegmentedControlSelectionIndicatorLocationDown;
    segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    segmentedControl.verticalDividerEnabled = YES;
    segmentedControl.verticalDividerColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    segmentedControl.verticalDividerWidth = 1.5f;
    [segmentedControl setTitleFormatter:^NSAttributedString *(HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl, NSString *title, NSUInteger index, BOOL selected) {
        NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE]}];
        return attString;
    }];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(loadTimeTableData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    int weekdayNumber = [components weekday];
    weekdayNumber = weekdayNumber - 1;

    switch (weekdayNumber) {
        case 1:
        case 7:
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;
            break;
        case 4:
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 3;
            break;
        case 5:
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 4;
            break;
        case 6:
            segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 5;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex animated:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

Comment: share code of that .

Comment: segmentedControl = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[NSLocalizedString(@"MONDAY", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"TUESDAY", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"WEDNESDAY", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"THURSDAY", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"FRIDAY", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"SATURDAY", nil)]];


    segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    CGFloat viewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, viewWidth, 45);


 segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 4;

Comment: you need to call this method    - (void)setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSUInteger)index animated:(BOOL)animated ..... for eg ..    [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:4 animated:YES];

Comment: @Zck i have called setSelectedSegmentIndex method but still segmentedControl is not scrolled to that index

Comment: is there any scrollView added in your viewcontroller ?

Comment: is this segmentedControl connected throught IBOutlets ?

Comment: @SavitaPal share your full updated code..

Comment: segmentedControl where declared ?

Comment: @KKRocks in my viewControllers .h file

Comment: ok is it IBoutlet ?

Comment: @KKRocks i have added HMSegmentedControl programmatically

Comment: @Zck My code is showing friday(i.e. index 4) as selected but friday is not visible in my view but when i scroll segmentControll then only friday is visible

Comment: @SavitaPal check [this](http://i.imgur.com/fS6Ye2H.png) it is output of your provided code with initial value as friday

Comment: @Zck Friday is selected in my project also but when i scroll my segmentcontrol then only friday is visible

Comment: @Zck i have added screenshot in my question

Comment: @SavitaPal this problem does reflect on my side ..it scrolls automatically to selected index..

Comment: @Zck Do u have made any changes in my code for automatically scroll?

Comment: @Zck Okay, and thank you for your reply

Comment: @SavitaPal done .!?

Comment: Not yet but i am trying

Answer (score 0):

You should call `segementControl selected at index`method in `loadTimeTableData:`method.